# Swift UI .animation - avoid affecting all animatable values

Tags: swift, swiftui

With swiftUI is it possible to have .animation easing be different for different properties within the same view/object. For example - if I have a circle() - can I have the .trim animate with different easing than a .rotationEffect?

```
Circle()
   .trim(from: 0.0, to: myProgress)
   .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(myRot))
   .animation(.easeIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can do this

```
Circle()
   .trim(from: 0.0, to: myProgress)
   .animation(.easeOut)
   .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(myRot))
   .animation(.easeIn)
   .position(myPos)
   .animation(nil)
```

And each .animation affects only what's above it